# Moving databases and logins to another server SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have about 300 databases and 45 log ins that I would like to move to a new server. What tool would you use? Do you have a script that can accomplish that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can backup your databases and restore them to the new server. [MSSQLTips has a script for backing up all databases](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1070/simple-script-to-backup-all-sql-server-databases/). [SQL Shack](http://www.sqlshack.com/migrate-logins-database-different-server/) has some methods described on their site as well.

[Katherine Villyard has written a script on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/663937/backup-and-restore-all-databases-and-users-sql-server) that you may find useful.

You could also use SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) to migrate your database over to another instance. Pinal Dave has [an article on SQL Authority](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/05/27/sql-server-copy-database-from-instance-to-another-instance-copy-paste-in-sql-server/).

Comment: what about sql logins? will they available on restoring database?

Comment: Microsoft has a script for that: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/918992. Do the script first and then restore dbs